# app.yaml handlers mapping for large number of files

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'm moving from a Shared Hosting account to `Google App Engine`. 
And I'm just getting started.
I have many php files. 
like

```
-file1.php
-file2.php
/admin
    -file1.php
    -file2.php
/user
    -file1.php
```

I figured that I need to define `handlers` inside `app.yaml` for each file to be served.such as

```
- url: /file1\.php
  script: file1.php
- url: /admin/file1\.php
  script: admin/file1.php
```

Will I have to write mapping for every file served or there is some way I that files will be automatically served based on their path like the normal hosting account that runs on apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed in the docs:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref

You can use a wildcard regex to handle similar matches

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

or

```
- url: /(.+)\.php$
      script: \1.php
```